# Jackson2JsonMessageConverter serializing LocalDateTime in specific pattern

Tags: json, date, spring-boot

I am trying to send an event using RabbitMQ and SpringBoot.

`@Configuration` class:

```
  @Bean
   public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
            return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
```

Event class:

```
public class TheEvent{

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd::MM::yyyy")
    private  LocalDateTime date;
//setters getters

}
```

When I send  it, it arrives as:

```
{"month":"JULY","year":2018,"dayOfMonth":12,"dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","dayOfYear":193,"hour":16,"minute":29,"nano":835000000,"second":24,"monthValue":7,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}},"direction":1}"
```

How can I serialize this date object in predefined pattern?  (Remember that I just registering bean Jackson2JsonMessageConverter)

Also tried this:

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {      
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

Comment: Inject the pre-created `ObjectMapper` into the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` else you get one without the Java8 date time module .

Comment: Not working, see update.

Comment: Setting `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` to `true` will write them as timestamps (seconds in epoch). Also do you have the proper dependencies? Which boot/spring version are you using? And which `LocalDateTime` the JDK or JodaTime one?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 4):

It works for me:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
}
```

In project I used RabbitListener and that Jackson2JsonMessageConverter

Listener:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${spring.rabbitmq.queue}")
@Transactional
public void receiveSocialPost(SocialPost socialPost) {
}
```

Comment: Please add some additional context to your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! after spending 6hrs plus